# Ubuntu 19.10 - /dev/mapper/vgubuntu-root issues

Tags: boot, grub2, xfce

I think I have run into a situation where `xrdp`, `sddm` and `xfce4` have stopped my computer from working. After removing `xrdp` (after a no gui from `xfce4`) ubuntu 19.10 read the following message on boot `/dev/mapper/vgubuntu-root: clean xxx/xxx blocks.`

From what I can see <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>works and I am able to do commands, boot into `grub` too and update boot paths. But `fsck` wont run due to mounted `root`, tried removing Nvidia packages / drivers and upgrading OS. None of which work.

Can I ask if this a secure boot issue or something with gnome as the OS is not getting beyond this message, yet I can talk to the kernel?

Comment: This is rather confusing. Xubuntu doesn't use `sddm` (Kubuntu & Lubuntu do) and yes you need to `umount` a partition before you `fsck` it (most of us achieve it via the use of live-media as it's easier).  From what I can see you don't have a secure boot issue, but seem mostly confused. and your mention of XFCE/GNOME/packages-from-other flavors wasn't explained or how they relate, nor what you're actually running (other than 19.10). The `fsck` message you mention is likely the result of an unclean shutdown on the prior boot, causing the system to fix any errors caused by unclean shutdown

Comment: The sddm was recommended as an alternative to lightdm or gdm3 for xrdp but did not work. The system has been restarted by sudo shutdown -r now after removal.

I was expect gnome GUI to return but instead the boot message is try to read blocks on a SSD which just sits there for hours. I was wondering if a boot-repair is best or fsck first as I cant see to get past this message when using recovery menu.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

So after a little looking around for 16.04 issues, I found [a post on Superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/1106174/boot-ubuntu-16-04-into-command-line-do-not-start-gui) relating to lightdm being the issue.

Commands run at the error message <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>

```
sudo systemctl disable lightdm.service
sudo systemctl enable lightdm.service
```

Reboot

If still no screen run:

```
sudo systemctl start lightdm.service
```

So I would recommend from there repairing lightdm gui.

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall lightdm
```

Followed by:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/lightdm start (for Unity)
```

Answer (score 0):

If it says `/dev/mapper/vgubuntu-root: clean xxx/xxx blocks.` then you don't have to fsck all disk. You can choose `Advanced Options for Ubuntu`, then choose proper kernel with `recovery mode`. Most probably you will be redirected to initramfs, you can run this code to solve disk problems: `fsck -f /dev/mapper/vgubuntu-root`

Comment: Hi There, I did try the process unfortunately this did not work even after umonting. It looks like the kernel was updated to 19.10 has stopped the file sytem progressing further for lvm. I have also checked the drivers and this has not repaired it either.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error on Ubuntu 20.04 after some changes in system trying to prevent external monitor flickering. After a lot of reading I was able to run system just:

```
sudo apt install lightdm
```

after install I've selected gdm3 as my DM